# broadleaf - failed to execute goal

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am following these easy steps https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/running-locally
but I am stuck at step 2 already ´mvn spring-boot:run´ gives me the following error:
Failed to execute goal on project boot-community-demo-admin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com-mycompany-community:boot-community-demo-admin:jar1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

feels like the pom.xml is not correct.

I believe it's looking for mycompany-community which doesn't exist http://nexus.broadleafcommerce.org/nexus/content/groups/community-snapshots/com/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You Can run using the eclipse it will run successfully with out giving any errors. here is the link to run using eclipse

Link: https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/ide-setup/eclipse-setup

It Will Work Fine While Running Using Eclipse.  I Also checked in my System it is working fine with eclipseIDE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to follow step 1c in the docs to `mvn install` from the root of the project. Did you do that part?